# batch script to search file better or close to window search

Tags: windows, batch-file

this batch script to search file better

using "find" its just ordinary...and need to type exactly the file name "file 1.txt" "file2.txt" "file letter.txt"

and exactly folder location...

any other way?

just try type "file"

its show all file with name "file"

"file 1.txt" 
"file2.txt" 
"file letter.txt"

and have number 
1 . "file 1.txt" 
2 . "file2.txt" 
3 . "file letter.txt"

and enter the number to select the file what we want...
and it will be open.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if exist log del log
set "token=%~1"
if not defined token (
    echo Search for what string?
    set /p token=^>
    echo.
)
set a=0
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b ^| find "%token%"') do (
    set /a a+=1
    echo !a!. %%A
    echo !a!. %%A >>log
)
echo.
echo Enter number of file to open.
set /p op=^>

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%A in (log) do (
    if %%A EQU %op% start %%B
)
del log
```

the problem is
when enter the number...batch otomatic close...file wont open...

any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

you might try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set /p "spat=Enter search pattern: "
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('dir /b /s /a-d \%spat%*.txt 2^>nul^|findstr /ri "%spat%[^a-z]"^|findstr /rn $') do set "$%%a=%%~b"&set /a fcnt+=1
if not defined fcnt (echo Error! Not such file "%spat%".&goto:eof)
:loop
for /f "tokens=1*delims==$" %%a in ('set "$" 2^>nul') do echo %%a.%%~b
set /p "fno=Enter file number to run: "
echo %fno%|findstr "[1-9][0-9]*" >nul || (echo Error! Try again.&goto:loop)
if %fno% gtr %fcnt% (echo Error! Enter number between 1-%fcnt%. Try again.&goto:loop)
for /f "tokens=1*delims==$" %%a in ('set "$%fno%"') do "%%~b"
```

Comment: 1. file1.txt and 2. file2.txt
___________________________________
echo Enter number of file to open.
set /p op=^>

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%A in (log) do (
    if %%A EQU %op% start %%B
)
del log
___________________________________

when i enter the number to select the file,
script doesnt work...

how to fix this?